# Style editor in uDig

Tags: geoserver

I added layers from Geoserver, I have line objects. But when I open style editor in uDig, I have only WMS Named Style. I thought I could change for example colors by attributes, but I don't how to do it when it offers me only WMS Named Style. I'm working with uDig and Geoserver for the first time so please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the layer as a WMS then UDig only allows you to work with the named styles provided by the server. Try adding as a WFS layer so that UDig can see the vectors to style.